# float type with . and ,

Tags: java

I wrote this code:
For each line, it should take the
weighted average of these numbers with weights 0.2, 0.4, and 0.4, and it should
print out the averaged value on a seperate line on the standard output. For
example, for the input below

```
45.00 67.00 98.00
89.00 23.00 89.00
```

it should produce

```
75.00
62.60
```

It works when i write, for example 45,6 but it doesn't when i write 45.6. 
This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class paket {
   public static void main (String [] args){
       Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
       float num1,num2,num3,result;

       while(input.hasNext()){

            num1=input.nextFloat();
            num2=input.nextFloat();
            num3=input.nextFloat();

            result= (float) (num1*0.2+num2*0.4+num3*0.4);

            System.out.println("Result is  " +result);
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: The comma-period thing is probably caused by some language or localization feature. You probably set your computer (or Java detected something like this) to use commas to separate decimals from integers

Comment: Sounds like a locale problem. Either change your system locale or in your code use `Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en","US"));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your locale before parsing the numbers:

```
Locale.setDefault(new Locale("en", "US"));
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextFloat(Unknown Source) but now i have this problem

Comment: Where did you put the locale change instruction? You should set it as the first instruction in the main.

Comment: Okay, I put after the scanner, now it solved. Thanks you very much!

Comment: That resets your Locale for your whole app. It's probably fine in this case, since the app as posted is just the Scanner - but as a general approach, it's pretty suboptimal, since it affects things like date and time formats and all number formatting throughout the application.

Comment: Glad I could help you! :) @GrantGainey you are right, but, as you said, this will affect all number formatting throughout the application, which I think is what he needs in this specific case: if he's going to input dotted floats he probably wants an output with the same format.

Answer (score 3):

A Scanner relies on a Locale to decide how to interpret its input. As other comments have noted, you're running on a system that assumes ',' is the decimal-point, rather than '.'

You can change the Locale your 'input' Scanner uses with

```
input.useLocale(Locale.US);
```

to have it interpret floats as using '.' for the decimal point.

You can set it back to your system's default with

```
input.reset();
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the locale when parsing, this way you support both . and , depending on what the user have chosen:

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());      
Number number = format.parse("1,234");   
double d = number.doubleValue();
```